# Connection refuse while connecting to sonar from gitlab

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I am facing issue while configuring Gitlab pipeline with SonarQube.
Gitlab running on `localhot` port `80` and Sonar running on `localhost` port `9000` in the same local linux machine.

If I am executing command from local linux terminal to connect with Sonar, it works fine, but same thing throwing error in Gitlab pipeline.

Command to execute from Terminal and pipeline:

`dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"project" /d:sonar.login=username /d:sonar.password=password /d:sonar.host.url=http://127.0.0.1:9000`

After executing above command it work fine but in Gitlab pipeline getting bellow error.

`Failed to request and parse 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/server/version': Connection refused (127.0.0.1:9000)`

```
stages:
  - sonar

Gitlab Pipeline:
sonarqube-check:
  stage: sonar
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
 task cache
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script: 
      - "apt-get update"
      - "apt-get install --yes openjdk-11-jre"
      - "dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner"
      - "export PATH=\"$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools\""
      - "dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"trukkerfinops" /d:sonar.login=username /d:sonar.password=password /d:sonar.host.url=http://127.0.0.1:9000"
      - "dotnet build"
      - "dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login=\"$SONAR_TOKEN\""
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - main
```

Runner configuration:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "devops"
  url = "http://localhost/"
  token = "token"
  executor = "docker"
  clone_url = "http://machine_ip"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "dind"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Console log:

```
$ dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"project" /d:sonar.login=username /d:sonar.password=password /d:sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.6
Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
13:52:04.682  Updating build integration targets...
13:52:04.781  Failed to request and parse 'http://localhost:9000/api/server/version': Cannot assign requested address (localhost:9000)
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address (localhost:9000)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I have tried many more options from google but no luck till yet

Answer (score 0):

To make HTTP request please add `--net=host` to your code

Comment: Added in the code like below but still getting issue `dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"project" /d:sonar.login=username /d:sonar.password=password --net=127.0.0.1:9000`   this is the error what now getting   `Unrecognized command line argument: --net=127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: Can you use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I used both option even machine IP also tried 127.0.0.1 localhost machineip everything giving same issue